# Multiple Vagrant Boxes Running at Once (on different ports)

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I had a version controlled project with my Vagrantfile with some bootstrap scrips.

I wanted the same setup but in a different project, so I copied everything over and changed the remote origin and so on to create a brand new project.

Next I changed the Vagrantfile port. It used to be 4567 but now I changed it to 45678 in the hope that I can access each site locally from a different port.

(i.e. access site A from 4567, but at the same time be able to access site B from 45678)

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 45678, guest: 80
```

Both Vagrantfiles use the same basebox:

```
config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
```

Now I tried to `vagrant up`, but I am told:

```
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: VirtualBox VM is already running.
```

I assumed this would be a different box. Can I have both running at once?
Is the problem that they're both called `default`?
Theres no way in the Vagrantfile to change that, if thats the case it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have copied also hidden `.vagrant` folder with reference to existing virtual machine.

Try to remove it.